# BF3 Mortar kills

Tags: battlefield-3

When mortaring, there is always the risk of being mortared back, so it's a good idea to keep mobile i.e. mortar, then move and redeploy. Now, when you move and kill someone with a mortar, it displays as (in my case) AlbortoTobor [KILLED] , as opposed to AlbortTobor [M224 MORTAR].

So, do these instances of [KILLED] still count towards the mortar tally...?

Comment: I assume you mean: you fire a mortar round, pick up and move and while you are in the process of moving, the round kills someone and it says [KILLED] instead of [M224 MORTAR]?

Comment: Yep. That's the lingo...

Comment: As far as I can tell, they do, but I've only got a couple of mortar kills so I'll let someone with more experience in the mortar department answer

Comment: I believe [KILLED] is displayed in place of [M224 MORTAR] when the killing damage is dealt by the other players exploding mortar tube.  So, the more general question would be:  When I destroy a vehicle with a given weapon, and the destruction of that vehicle kills a player, is the kill applied to that weapon?

Comment: @tQuarella, I believe it is not applied to that weapon in this case. If you bring a house down with a tank, crushing someone, it counts as experience for the tank, and adds to your career kills, but I don't think it counts toward tank kills. Likewise, if a rocket causes a tank to blow up, killing the person beside it, then I believe it will either say [KILLED] or sometimes you won't get credit, and it will just say [BAD LUCK]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK. So I can confirm that if you leave the mortar, and then get a mortar kill displaying as [KILLED], that it does NOT add to your tally.

So much for deploy and move if you want that medal...

Comment: Do you only ever see [KILLED] when moving the mortar?

Comment: Yeah. If you are still manning the mortar when the shell hits and scores the kill, it will display as [M224 MORTAR]. Otherwise it shows as [KILLED]. I'll try and get screenshots when i get home.